# Android - Change Texture of Bitmap GLES20 - Fragment Shader

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, shader

I want to change a pixel color of the Bitmap with OpenGLES, by picking it with e.g. coordinates. What do I have to do? Any advices?

```
fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.test_Image);
riGraphicTools.sp_Image = GLES20.glCreateProgram();            
GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, fragmentShader);

public static final String test_Image =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "varying vec2 v_texCoord;" +
        "uniform sampler2D s_texture;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = texture2D( s_texture, v_texCoord );" +
        "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think ES 2.0 supports writeable textures, so instead of modifying sp_image on the fly, just render to texture with an FBO and use that texture in place of your original sp_image.

Comment: thank you for your answer. can u show me an example code for that?